# is GPS error the same on two devices near each other?

Tags: gps, android-gps

There are a fair number of GPS questions here...

The GPS is not always completely accurate.
If two devices are nearby, will they have the same error?

I have GPS in my lawnmower. If an app subtracts the GPS location of the mower and the GPS on the phone, will the error cancel out, so it can show the direction to the mower with greater accuracy than just looking at the GPS location of the mower on the map?

Answer (score 1):

No, the error can be different even if the devices are of the same model.
The error is due to signal diversity which can change even if you move the receiver even a bit, location of the antenna (which is definitely not the same) and the accuracy of the GPS's components. All of these can vary even for two devices of the same model. If the models are not the same, they can be using different technologies, like SiRF3 or SiRF4 so once again, the error probably not be the same.